# java user interface(JCheckBoxMenuItem)

Tags: java, swing, gui, ui

Ребят, привет. Я использую `JCheckBoxMenuItem` для того чтобы включать и выключать `resizable`, но каждый раз когда у `JCheckBoxMenuItem` ставлю `setState(true)`, у меня будто окно перезапускается. Как правильнее реализовать этот момент?

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public int width = 300;
    public int height = 350;

    private JPanel panel;

    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenu view;

    private JCheckBoxMenuItem resize;

    public Window() {       
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        view = new JMenu("Veiw");
        resize = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Resizable");
        resize.setState(false);
        resize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(resize.getState()) {
                    setResizable(true);
                }
                else {
                    setResizable(false);
                }

            }
        });
        view.add(resize);
        menubar.add(view);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle("Chat");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня ваша программа при снятии галочки (`setResizable(false)`) меняет размер окна. Это известная проблема у Windows-версии Java ([вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560527/frame-and-canvas-grow-larger-than-specified/), [JDK-8090028](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090028), [JDK-8089008](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089008), [JDK-8116047](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116047)), но не похоже, чтобы она имела нормальное решение. Проявляется в том, что после установки запрета изменения размера, отступы от края окна (`getInsets()`) уменьшаются, и у содержимого окна появляется больше места для отображения. Подозреваю, что увеличение размеров окна зависит от темы Windows.

Рекомендуют вызвать `setResizable(false)` один раз при создании окна, после чего вызвать `pack()` и позволить Layout Manager и компонентам решить, какой размер окна им нужен.

В вашем случае, можете сделать вот так:

```
resize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final Insets oldInsets = getInsets();
        final Rectangle oldBounds = getBounds();
        setResizable( resize.getState() );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
            Insets newInsets = getInsets(); 
            Rectangle newBounds = getBounds();

            newBounds.x = oldBounds.x - (newInsets.left - oldInsets.left);
            newBounds.y = oldBounds.y - (newInsets.top - oldInsets.top);

            newBounds.width = oldBounds.width + (newInsets.left - oldInsets.left) + (newInsets.right - oldInsets.right);
            newBounds.height = oldBounds.height + (newInsets.top - oldInsets.top) + (newInsets.bottom - oldInsets.bottom);
            setBounds( newBounds );
        } );
    }
});
```

Код произведет пересчет положения и размера окна на экране с учетом изменившихся границ. Окно все равно может заметно дернуться, но хотя бы останется на прежнем месте и будет нужного размера.